# Removing profile settings from a profile that no longer exists

Tags: iphone, internet, configuration-profiles

At some point in the past, I installed [Snappli](http://snappli.com/). At some point later, I removed it. However, some part of Snappli is still installed, because *ifconfig.me* and *whatsmyip* both report that I'm being proxy'd through Snappli (see below):

How do I remove the Snappli proxy settings from my phone, even though the Profile is gone?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My best tip would probably be to install the app again, with the profile and all of that, and then remove the profile again, then deleting the app and see if that helps.

It's hard to tell what might be causing the problem – you're sure there are no proxy settings in place anywhere and that the profile is deleted?

Edit: It seems there are some ghost settings you're unable to change. Your best chance would be to reset all the network settings (Settings -> General -> Reset -> Reset Network Settings), or restoring your iPhone to factory settings.

Comment: Unfortunately, the app is no longer available. I've confirmed that the profile has been removed, and that there are no proxy settings that I can see anywhere.

Comment: Please see the updated answer.

Comment: Glad it worked out for you :)

Answer (score -1):

Just to confirm, you have gone into Settings > General and looked for a sub-section called Profiles? Proxy settings are set only through configuration profiles to my knowledge. If you see no section called "Profiles" then there are none installed.

Short of that you may have a device corruption. In such a case I recommend you follow Emil's advice above to Reset Network Settings. In a worst-case scenario you can Restore as new (not from iCloud backup) to ensure everything is new, though hopefully you can avoid that.